# checkbox control all the same css class id color in servlet

Tags: css, html, servlets

I have a check box with many span tags, some of the have the same css class id.

What i am looking for is:

When the checkbox is clicked, the color of the span tags which have the same css class id  to be changed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show up some code, what you are supposed to do? Because the things you have described may confuse many users, so you might not be able to get exact solution

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, the first answer replied me correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are looking for:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
        $('span.' + myClass).css("color","red");
     }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NnFhM/

If you want to add/remove a class on check/uncheck:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
        var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
        $('span.' + myClass).toggleClass('edit');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NnFhM/1/

Comment: Yes, this is my request, also i want when the checkbox is unchecked to take the previous class id! and also to have a css block not just a color! Thanks a lot

Comment: Check update. It will add/remove a css class. This way you can easily add more css properties.